# chef docker_container use health_check

Tags: docker, chef-infra

I am trying to use the health_check docker feature in chef, but I am getting the following error:

```
had an error: Docker::Error::ClientError: Interval in Healthcheck cannot be less than 1ms
```

I have the following chef config:

```
docker_container my_contianer do
  command container_command
  action :run
  repo repo
  tag tag
  user 'app'
  restart_policy 'always'
  env envs
  volumes volumes
  port [
    "80:8000"
  ]
  memory max_container_memory
  if container_config.key?('health_check')
    health_check(
      'Test' =>
        [
          'curl localhost:8000/health || exit 1',
        ],
      'Interval' => 30,
      'Timeout' => 10,
      'Retries' => 10,
      'StartPeriod' => 0
    )
  end
end
```

I also tried '30s' and it did not work, any idea how should I use this health_check function?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I managed to achieve it by the following:

```
docker_container my_docker do
  command container_command
  action :run
  repo repo
  tag tag
  user 'app'
  restart_policy 'always'
  env envs
  volumes volumes
  port [
    "80:8000"
  ]
  memory max_container_memory
  if container_config.key?('health_check')
    # Running every 30 seconds
    # each time tries for 10 times with delay of 30s if after 10 times fails it will restart the docker
    health_check({
      'Test': [
        'CMD-SHELL',
        'curl -f --retry 10 --max-time 10 --retry-delay 30 --retry-max-time 20 -f localhost:8000/health || kill 1'
      ],
      'Interval': 30000000000,
      'Timeout': 1000000000,
      'Retries': 3
    })

  end
```